# Targeting a single item in a nested group with nth-of-type

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I thought it might be possible to target an item higher up in the DOM without targeting those below it. My goal was to only color the 2nd `li` and leave the rest black with one rule.

```
<ul class="mega">
  <li>this is top level
    <ul>
      <li>this is the only item to color
         <ul>
           <li>first item</li>
           <li>second item</li>
           <li>third item</li>
           <li>fourth item</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The one rule is:

```
ul.mega > li > ul > li:nth-of-type(1)  {
   color: red;
}
```

But all those below are red as well. So I added a second rule which works, but was hoping to be more economical in my coding. Anyway to do this?

```
ul.mega > li > ul > li:nth-of-type(1)  {
   color: red;
}
//second rule
ul.mega > li > ul > li ul  {
   color: black;
}
```

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/breadwild/pen/NWpEQgK) with the code.